# Tracking Repeat Attendees

Tags: search, reports, searchkit

I am looking to report on how many of our event attendees have previously attended an event, but I can't seem to find a way in search-kit.

Search for "contacts who have registered for [event x] who also attended any other event".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SE!

Yes, search for Contacts and link twice to 'Contact Participants'.

If you want those who attended two particular events:

[image]

If you want those who attended the Fall Fundraiser and another (any) event:

[image]

You probably want to add some other conditions like participant status.